# Filter to only nodes with an image in an imagefield in Views 3

Tags: 7, views

In my view, I want to include/exclude nodes that do not have an image in a specific field with exposed filter. The field allows an unlimited number of images. I don't care about the exact quantity, just that there are more than 0. How do I create this filter?

Answer (score 0):

'Is not empty' is an option for the operator of filters.  Did you try that?

So you can add a filter to your view, and just select that as your operator.  Here's a screenshot to help:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the field "title" may be empty

Comment: But I've set up the filter to be for the field 'image', not 'title'.  Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding your comment?